Checking and Pasting Data from another sheet using VBA
I have two sheets: Example Data and Dashboard.
I want to check each cell of Column A and B in the example data sheet and if either has "N", it takes the value from Column C and D and pastes them into Column A and B of the Dashboard Sheet. The Dashboard sheet should be able to automatically update if there's a change in Column A of the Example Data sheet.
Example Data Sheet



Column A
Column B
Column C
Column D




Y
N
Tim
4/3


Y
Y
Dana
3/36



Dashboard



Column A
Column B




Tim
4/3



I've tried to use excel functions but the cells in Column B are merged and it leaves blank spaces and I want the table to be formatted nicely.

Merging cells always leads to more problems than if ever solves. Could you unmerge the cells? It would also be useful to se what you have tried

What does "if there's a change in Column A" mean? In VBA, it often means that you manually enter a value. Also, what about a change in column B? Your scarce sample data doesn't show any merged cells (a screenshot would help). Please clarify by adding more information to your post (question).

This can be done without VBA. Get rid of merged cells. Use "Center across selection" instead.
Here is a screenshot of data that follows your data sample. Next to it, a filtered list of just the Name and Result columns for the rows where either QuestionA or QuestionB have the letter N.
=FILTER(C2:D7,(A2:A7="n")+(B2:B7="n"))


This is a dynamic arrary formula and it is only entered in one cell. It automatically spills down into as many rows as needed. You must ensure that there is sufficient space on your dashboard sheet to avoid errors.

If that resolved your issue, please mark the answer as described in the [tour]. If it didn't, please leave a comment, so I can follow up.

Thank you for the tip! It worked with the unmerged cells but unfortunately for formatting reasons, the cells have to be merged. Is there a way for the merged cells to repeat the data in the upper-left most cell?

It's not clear which cells are merged. Please provide that detail.
